# How to show array in reverse in VUE?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vuejs2

I have simple array with items in which I `push` new ones from time to time. New items comes via `ajax`;

```
items.push({id: 1, title: 'a'});
items.push({id: 2, title: 'b'});
items.push({id: 3, title: 'c'});
items.push({id: 4, title: 'd'});
```

The main thing is that I need to show them in reverse like:

1. 4, d
2. 3, c
3. 2, b
4. 1, a

The problem is that I cant use `unshift` as I need to have `index` to items as I will need to do interactions with specific items.

So basically I'm searching for a way to `push` items but show them like it was `unshift`. Not actually reverse array.

Comment: You could use array.reverse, or array.reduceRight to reverse the array when you are done pushing values I guess. Using reduceRight you could even add the original index to the object so it is available as property.

Comment: @user3492940 i dont need actually reverse it. I need only show in table it in reverse.

Comment: so I can imagine you are using the v-repeat directive. Perhaps you could call array.reverse inline in the directive: <div v-repeat="item in array.reverse()"></div>. I don't use vue a lot but I can imagine this would work.

Comment: I am beginner at Vue but I think `<li v-for="item in items | orderBy 'id' -1" track-by="id">` should work

Comment: @Deancoakley there are no such `id`. I need to use `index` instead

Answer (score 5):

Just use a `computed` property and you're done. The `reverse` method will reverse the items in an array in place, so I used the `slice` method to create a new one.

As for the unshift thing, the update order is already there when you use the `push` method, so the order is just as simple as reverse the original array, you don't need to worry about it.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  computed: {
    reversedArr() {
      return this.items.slice().reverse()
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.items.push({id: 1, title: 'a'})
    this.items.push({id: 2, title: 'b'})
    this.items.push({id: 3, title: 'c'})
    this.items.push({id: 4, title: 'd'})
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <h3>Original</h3>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in items">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Reversed</h3>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in reversedArr">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    items:[]
  },
  mounted(){
    this.items.push({id: 1, title: 'a'})
    this.items.push({id: 2, title: 'b'})
    this.items.push({id: 3, title: 'c'})
    this.items.push({id: 4, title: 'd'})
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <div v-for="(item,index) in items.reverse()">
    {{index+1}}. {{item.id}},{{item.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.`

Comment: @Kin this code snippet works, so your error must be caused by a typo in your code. Are you sure you're calling `arr.reverse()` and not `this.reverse()`?

Comment: You can go even simpler by calling `items.reverse()` inline. `<div v-for="(item, index) in items.reverse()">`

Comment: beware `reverse()` modifies the array, so you first need to make a copy of it with `slice()` as mentioned in @kevguy's answer. Otherwise you will get unexpected results whenever you push new items.

Comment: ⚠️ This is not a good solution. If you have arrays of any significant length you get the warning `[Vue warn]: Maximum recursive updates exceeded.`. Instead, use @kevguy s method instead